# Custom App class bypassing autogenerated file

Tags: c#, wpf

When I create Wpf project, I get default `App` class which is derived from `Application`.

I want to derive `App` from my own class (which of course inherits `Application`), but there is autogenerated `App.g.cs` file which define that `App` is derived form `Application`.

How can I turn off that autogenerated file?

Comment: I have useful hierarchy in my winforms projects, one entry point to confige,logging e.t.c, and I want to add this to my wpf project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the `<Application` tag in App.xaml to `<local:YourClass xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace"`

Alternatively, get rid of App.xaml and create the entire class yourself.

Answer (score 4):

When creating your own class derived from Application set the build action to ApplicationDefinition:

"Identifies the XAML markup file that contains the application definition (a XAML markup file whose root element is Application). ApplicationDefinition is mandatory when Install is true and OutputType is winexe. A WPF application and, consequently, an MSBuild project can only have one ApplicationDefinition."

Extract From [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970678%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

To turn off the creation of the autogenerated app.g.cs change the build action from "ApplicationDefinition" to "Page" and substitute your own entry point into the app.

Comment: No.  That compiles App.xaml files.  Normal `.cs` files should be compiled normally.

Comment: I edited my answer to apply to custom classes derived from Application as I realise normal cs files compile normally. Are you saying this only applies to a naked app.xaml without code behind? Doesn't seem well documented.

Comment: That build action is triggering the creation of App.g.cs which has the main entry point. Just editted my answer to reflect this.